# ImageView in ListView briefly shows previous image on scroll with RecycleElement enabled

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of the following class:

```
public class Set {
   public string IconUrl { get; set; }
}
```

This list is bound to a ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Sets}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Image Source="{Binding IconUrl}" />
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When the view loads and the user starts scrolling, the cells are reused and the Image briefly shows the previous image before the new image is downloaded and rendered.

Is there a way to prevent this kind of behavior without disabling RecycleElement?

Comment: Are you able to produce a small demo and I will take a closer look at what you have?  If so, my details are on my profile.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this but on `ViewCell` you have `Disappearing` and `Appearing` events that you can hook into.

You may want to look at releasing the image source on the `Disappearing` event handler, but sometimes this can occur sometime later I think from recollection, so you may also want to try releasing the image on the `Appearing` event handler that hopefully will be executed prior to the display on the screen?

Comment: I've tried the Disappearing event, unfortunately it doesn't consistently fire when i need it to. I'll try the Appearing event but im guessing that one will be even worse ;)

Answer (score 3):

We have solved this by manually setting the Image source to null to force the render of the new images. we achieve this by using OnBindingContextChanged Event of the ListView. Hope this helps.

Edited (Added code below):

We have something like this:

```
public class PeopleCell : ViewCell
{...

Image profileImage;

public PeopleCell()
{
    profileImage = new Image
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("f5f5f5"),
        Source = ImageSource.FromFile("profile_blankimage"),
    };...

protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
{
    base.OnBindingContextChanged();
    people = BindingContext as CustomerViewModel;


    if(people.Customer.Avatar != null)
       profileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(people.Customer.Avatar.Url));
```

Comment: How can i reference the Image from the OnBindingContextChanged event? Any chance you could add some code?

Comment: I have added some sample code that we have used, I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah a custom ViewCell, this means you arent using XAML right?

Comment: Nope, No XAML sorry that i missed that.

Comment: Can you include where you set the image source to null? I'm assuming in OnBindingContextChanged, but just want to make sure.